# How to specify default download path in selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How to specify default download path in selenium?

I using headless chrome in Docker.

```
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  chrome:
    container_name: chrome
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.9.1-actinium
    ports:
    - 4444:4444
```

and my code is below.

```
# ruby
          chrome_capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
            "chromeOptions" => {
              'prefs' => {
                'profile.default_content_settings.popups' => 0,
                'download.default_directory' => File.absolute_path(@download_path),
                'download.prompt_for_download' => false,
              }
            }
          )
          driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(
            :remote,
            url: "http://chrome:4444/wd/hub",
            desired_capabilities: chrome_capabilities,
          )
```

However, when I run the download in chrome, I get a download prompt.

How can I automatically download to the specified folder?

Answer (score 0):

You try this code and let me know.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.read_timeout = 60 # seconds

prefs = {
  download: {
    'prompt_for_download' => false,
    'default_directory' => "c:/foldername"
  },
  "credentials_enable_service" => false,
  "password_manager_enabled" => false
}

options = { prefs: prefs,
            options: { "excludeSwitches" => ["enable-automation", "load-extension"] } }

selenium_args = [:chrome, { http_client: client, options: options} ]
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(*selenium_args)
```

Comment: Your question is about how to specify the download folder. You could use :remote, that's not an issue. So Did you try out my code? Is it working?